# Em Python, verificar se o conteúdo de uma coluna está presente em outra coluna?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, ipython-notebook

estou no Jupyter Notebook trabalhando com Python.

Meu dataframe atual está com o seguinte formato - data.columns['nome', 'nome_arquivo', 'texto'].

[image: Imagem do dataframe]

Todoas as colunas são do tipo string, desejo, pegar a coluna 'nome' e verificar se todo o conteúdo dela é encontrado exatamente em alguma parte na string da coluna 'texto'. Desejo ter como resultado todos os registros verificados se encontrou ou não, conforme figura abaixo.

[image: Imagem do resultado esperado]

Posteriormente desejo ter este resultado exportado para csv.

Comment: Este código dá erro. Tenho um script que me dá apenas os resultados encontrados (data[['nome' in x for x in data['texto']]]), porém preciso de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tenho sua base então criei uma própria. Veja abaixo:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"nome": ["teste 1", "teste 2", "teste 3"], "nome_arquivo": ["um arquivo", "dois arquivos", "tres adivinha"], "texto": ["Aqui vc encontra um arquivo", "Aqui nao tem o texto", "tres adivinha está aqui"]})

>>> df
      nome   nome_arquivo                        texto
0  teste 1     um arquivo  Aqui vc encontra um arquivo
1  teste 2  dois arquivos         Aqui nao tem o texto
2  teste 3  tres adivinha      tres adivinha está aqui

>>> df["encontrado"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.nome_arquivo in x.texto, axis=1)

>>> df
      nome   nome_arquivo                        texto  encontrado
0  teste 1     um arquivo  Aqui vc encontra um arquivo        True
1  teste 2  dois arquivos         Aqui nao tem o texto       False
2  teste 3  tres adivinha      tres adivinha está aqui        True
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Oi @Paulo, muito obrigado, fluiu em partes, este comando gera um erro, mas gera o dataframe só com a coluna resultado. Segue o erro: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.

Estou procurando ver se consigo resolver este. Obrigado.

Comment: @Perciliano, melhor abrir outro post com o erro, o pedaço do código e, se possível, o dataset. Talvez apenas um pedaço como fiz gerando a resposta acima